# I just cannot seem to partition...(Windows Vista)

Tags: partitioning

All day I have been trying to partition my 285.62 GB hard drive on my laptop. I tried to disable hibernation and disabling swap (i.e paging), but it still doesn't work. After doing both of those, and restarting, I still have 3806 MB of available shrink space according to Disk Management. Any tips please? Or will Ubuntu automatically partition my hard drive anyway?
More Information:
I have Ubuntu already installed on my comp (only boot-able from a CD at the moment)
I want to have at least 50 GB set away for Ubuntu, yet the Disk Manager only allows for 3 GB.
I have an HP Pavilion Dv6 laptop
I don't know what more you want?

Comment: Can you add more information? Thanks.

Comment: Try running Windows's Disk Defragment tool. Sometimes the Disk Management service will refuse to resize a partition if certain data is being stored on a sector that is being removed from the partition.

Comment: Try using a third-party Partitioning tool.  http://www.partition-tool.com/download.htm  It's very useful.

Comment: You said ubuntu already installed but you need cd to boot it from? was it intentional? can you post an image of your disk. In windows run `diskmgmt.msc` and take a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

When installing Ubuntu, it will ask you if you want to A) erase all partitions/data and install a fresh setup B) partition the hard drive between Windows Vista and Ubuntu, thus creating a dual boot.

If you select to partition, you will then decide how much space to allocate to Ubuntu and windows.

Now if you still want to partition before installing, ill explain some basics. First of all, you can not edit partitions awhile the hard drive is mounted. Mounted means in use and communiting with your computer. So you can't edit the partitions on your Windows Vista hard drive while using it. You will have to use a Ubuntu live usb, boot into Ubuntu, unmount your vista hdd, then finally use gparted to edit your partitions. You could also install a second hard drive (if its a desktop) and then boot into whatever OS is on the hard drive, finally proceeding to unmout the vista hard drive, etc.

A word of caution: manually partitioning is very dangerous! Even erasing an empty partition of swap space can render all your data unreachable. Data recovery is messy business that you don't want to get caught in. The wisest action would be to let the Ubuntu partition do all the partitioning.

If this doesn't address your issue tell me in a comment.

Comment: THANKS. The moment you said "unmount" I said "Oh hell no." I will use Ubuntu for it. I hope this works.

Comment: Glad to help :) Installation is very easy, you will do just fine. Is your question answered?  If yes mark my answer as the solution, that way other people can benefit from your question.

Comment: If I answered your question correctly, could you mark it as solved so others can find it?